# Codeigniter Insert Batch fails over 195 rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I have a View with a list of items, the user can specify how many items belong in each room.

When The submit button is clicked, if the amount is >= 1 it is inserted in to a table in the DB.

my controller looks like this.

```
// Collect desired post arrays
$step = $this->input->post('quantity');
$item = $this->input->post('item_id');
$user = $this->input->post('user_id');

$rows = array();  # we'll store each row in this array

//// Setup a counter for looping through post arrays

$row_count = count($step);

for ($i = 0; $i < $row_count; $i++) { 
   if($step[$i] >= '1'){
      $rows[] = array(
         'quantity' => $step[$i],
         'i_id' => $item[$i],
         'u_id' => $user
      );    
   }
}

$this->db->insert_batch('item_quantity', $rows);
```

Now this works absolutely fine with 195 items inserted into the database, however over 195 it breaks.

Is this something to do with a limit on the insert batch function?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't related to the data you try to insert ?

Comment: the things i would check to start with are: is there enough server memory, does the script timeout, and is error reporting turned on? if you are running out of memory you may need to refactor your code to reduce the array size. Is it timing out, if so you might be able to get around the problem with a simple `set_time_limit(0);` this means you script can run till its finished. If error reporting is turned off you will be unable to see the message that the server is trying to display to u, you can turn this back on using `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. As Yellow Bird stated, check the array of data!

Comment: I don't think it is the data that is the problem, because 195 items can be inserted ok, error reporting is also turned on, If the query is run successful it should redirect to the next step, which is step 4, but when there is over 195 items it just refreshes the page.